Install app from github
am very new to Linux so I need your help!
I am trying to install file bot found on this git-hub
I am looking to install this app "https://github.com/barry-allen07/FB-Mod" on kubuntu 23.10, but I have no idea on how to do it, can someone pls help me, some step by step instructions

https://github.com/barry-allen07/FB-Mod/blob/master/COMPILING.md There are no instructions there for Linux.

Pls, take the tour and read help files, the links are in bottom of this page, when you have time, Also if the answer satisfies you pls accept it.

i am sorry, i missed the readme file, i am new to linux and the way it works with installations, add the github and i cant do comprehend a thing. I do thank you for the help!

It depends on what app you want to install, but for the one you want, the README says to download it from the releases tab here (click on amd64.deb). It says you need Java for it. If you don't already have it, you can either install Java 11 specifically (like it says) with sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre, or the latest LTS (currently 17 in 23.10) with sudo apt install default-jre in the terminal.

Java should automatically be installed as a dependency while installing the deb file

i am terribly sorry a missed this. Than you very much for your help!
